# blockdev --getsize64 equivalent in c++?

Tags: linux, c++

Is there a function equivalent to `blockdev --getsize64` in C++ to calculate `/dev/block/sdb` sizes without using `system()`?

from : Answer of Vojtech Trefny

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

// ...

const char* pathname="/dev/sda";
int fd = open(pathname, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    die("%s", strerror(errno));
}

uint64_t size;
if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &size) == -1) {
    die("%s", strerror(errno));
}

close(fd);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BLKGETSIZE64` [ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) or read it from `/sys/class/block/sdb/size` (size here is in 512 sectors).